# ImportPackage com.itextpdf into a Java Class in XPages

Tags: java, xpages

I have created a new Java Class which at this point simply attempts to

```
package ca.wfsystems.core;

importPackage(com.itextpdf);

public class PrintPDF {

}
```

however I have an error on the importPackage line:

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration
    - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete 
     EnumHeaderName

I believe I have the jar properly installed and it shows up in the package explorer under the WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/itextpdf-5.5.6.jar

I was using the example by Declan at http://www.qtzar.com/7plcn79gsvsw/

I have done a bit of Java but still on the steep part of the learning curve.

Comment: `importPackage()` is available for SSJS, not Java. Use `import ...;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't import packages using `importPackage`: that is not even a Java keyword. If you want to import everything in a package, replace that line with:

```
import com.itextpdf.*;
```

Note that there is no notion of hierarchical relationship between packages in Java, so if you also want to import something from a subpackage, you need to import that subpackage explicitly:

```
import com.itextpdf.name.of.subpackage.*;
```

Comment: did that and it says com.itextpdf.* could not be resolved so there would appear to be something wrong with how I got the jar file into my database,

Comment: That's not the problem you describe in the question. You need to make sure that jar file is on the classpath.

Comment: Andy I had to add the jar file to the build path - did not do that automatically. In any case it now works

Answer (score 1):

Of course the syntax has to be correct as stated by the other answers.

Then you *could* add the jar as an OSGi plugin which is what I am doing now. It is a lot cleaner to manage and work with - and I guess that is *"the way"* do do it in the Java world.

I wrote a couple of articles about [how to wrap a jar as a plugin](http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/wrap-an-existing-jar-file-into-a-plug-in/) and [how to install it on the server and in Designer](http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/deploy-an-eclipse-update-site-to-ibm-domino-and-ibm-domino-designer/) :-)

/John